# Drainage issue in the yard

Tags: drainage, backyard

Below is drawing of our yard sloping (depicted by arrows along the lines) and what I'd like to do to fix the drainage issue.

During the rain, water comes from our neighbors as well as from street towards the spot marked by 'dry wall'. Iinside of the fence yard is sloped towards storm grate. Sometimes a lot of water accumulates next to the fence and along the slope leading to storm grate. I am thinking of installing dry well or catch basin at the highest point to the left of our fence and lay french drain towards storm grate and place catch basin next to it.

Should I use dry well or catch basin to collect water before it's taken to storm grate? Will dry well be overkill in this situation? Perhaps someone can offer another solution?

[image]

Comment: "dry well or catch basin at the _highest_ point" Water doesn't stay at the highest point of anything for long. You need to install that at the low spot. Is this spot on your side of the fence or the other side, it's not clear from your drawing. Instead of a single collection point, you might run the French drain along the fence to pick up water wherever it want to collect, then divert it to the square dry well/catch basin on the right of the drawing.

Comment: Could you notate what **exists now** *.vs.* what **you are thinking about adding** because the net effect of the drawing is that the distinction is lost, and makes more confusion... I guess the square thing exists, and all else is new? Then there's the practical issue of "do you own the land on the other side of your fence" to put a catch basin there?

Comment: @FreeMan The yard is sloped in such a way that water is flowing towards the storm drain (box on the right). I was also thinking of adding french drain along the fence so that it flows into the catch basin on left and ultimately makes it way to the storm drain (via another catch basin near it).

Comment: @Ecnerwal The other side of the fence is my property as well, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already formulated the solutions and as others have pointed out there is no need for a catch basin or drywell. The water is collecting along the fence because the fence is acting as a barrier. Adding the french drain on the left side of the fence connected to a "T" located at the low point allows the water to flow under the fence. If the water is collecting in pools along the slope to the storm drain, its because there are low spots along the flow path.  Adding the french drain from the "T" to the storm will help drains those low spots. 
You might have to punch a hole in the side of the storm drain to connect the french drain or end it at the top edge of the storm drain.

[image]